# Is there a way to disable the fullscreen app search in 18.04?

Tags: unity, graphics, 18.04, fullscreen

I'm coming from 16.04 and much prefer the pop-out style of the app search.

Comment: Are you signing in with the Unity interface or a different one?

Comment: yee using Unity